# search data in string - Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String like :
"name:lala,id:1234,phone:123"
but for example I want to get only the id (the numbers)  - 1234

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I know I can just search for the start index ( using substring or indexof)  of Id and then get the int but I have a longer string with many data so I thought there is something better than this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more generic than the other solutions:

```
    String foo = "name:lala,id:1234,phone:123";
    // get all all key/value pairs into an array
    String[] array = foo.split(",");
    // check every key/value pair if it starts with "id"
    // this will get the id even if it is at another position in the string "foo"
    for (String i: array) {
        if (i.startsWith("id:")) {
            System.out.println(i.substring(3));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions with a capturing group for that:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("id:(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("name:lala,id:1234,phone:123");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid regex and use String#split method like this:

```
String str = "name:lala,id:1234,phone:123";
String id = str.split(",")[1].split(":")[1]; // sets "1234" to variable id
```

OR using some regex with String#replaceAll:

```
String id = str.replaceAll("^.*?,id:(\\d+),.*$", "$1"); // sets "1234" to variable id
```